# Help with regular expressions (Parsing Wikipedia Markup) in PHP

Tags: php, regex, wikipedia, wikitext

I have this bit of text that I want to remove from a page I am fetching from Wikipedia.

```
{{Historical populations|type=USA
| 1698|4937
| 1712|5840
| 1723|7248
| 1737|10664
| 1746|11717
| 1756|13046
| 1771|21863
| 1790|33131
| 1800|60515
| 1810|96373
| 1820|123706
| 1830|202589
| 1840|312710
| 1850|515547
| 1860|813669
| 1870|942292
| 1880|1206299
| 1890|1515301
| 1900|3437202
| 1910|4766883
| 1920|5620048
| 1930|6930446
| 1940|7454995
| 1950|7891957
| 1960|7781984
| 1970|7894862
| 1980|7071639
| 1990|7322564
| 2000|8008288
| 2008*|8363710
|footnote=Beginning 1900, figures are for consolidated city of five boroughs. Sources: 1698–1771,{{cite book|last=Greene and Harrington|first=|title=American Population Before the Federal Census of 1790|publisher=|location=New York|year=1932|isbn=|pages=}}, as cited in: {{cite book|last=Rosenwaike|first=Ira|title=Population History of New York City|publisher=Syracuse University Press|location=Syracuse, N.Y.|year=1972|isbn=0815621558|page=8}} 1790–1990,Gibson, Campbell.[http://www.census.gov/population/www/documentation/twps0027.html Population of the 100 Largest Cities and Other Urban Places in the United States:1790 to 1990], [[United States Census Bureau]], June 1998. Retrieved June 12, 2007. *2008 est[http://factfinder.census.gov/servlet/SAFFPopulation?_event=Search&geo_id=16000US3403940&_geoContext=01000US%7C04000US34%7C16000US3403940&_street=&_county=new+york+city&_cityTown=new+york+city&_state=04000US36&_zip=&_lang=en&_sse=on&ActiveGeoDiv=geoSelect&_useEV=&pctxt=fph&pgsl=160&_submenuId=population_0&ds_name=null&_ci_nbr=null&qr_name=null&reg=null%3Anull&_keyword=&_industry=Census Data for New York city, New York], [[United States Census Bureau]]. Retrieved June 12, 2007.
}}
```

The following part I wish to keep as plain text also (but not including parts wrapped with "{{" and "}}"

```
New York is the most populous city in the United States, with an estimated 2008 population of 8,363,710(up from 7.3 million in 1990). This amounts to about 40.0% of New York State's population and a similar percentage of the metropolitan regional population. Over the last decade the city's population has been increasing and demographers estimate New York's population will reach between 9.2 and 9.5 million by 2030.{{cite web |title=New York City Population Projections by Age/Sex and Borough, 2000-2030 |publisher=[[New York City Department of City Planning]] |month=December | year=2006 |url=http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/pdf/census/projections_report.pdf |format=PDF |accessdate=2008-09-01}} See also {{cite news |last=Roberts, Sam |title=By 2025, Planners See a Million New Stories in the Crowded City |publisher=New York Times |date=February 19, 2006 |url=http://www.nytimes.com/2006/02/19/nyregion/19population.html?ex=1298005200&en=c586d38abbd16541&ei=5090&partner=rssuserland&emc=rss |accessdate=2008-09-01}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any examples of Regexs you've already tried?

Answer (score 3):

The current code I am using is the following to clean a Wiki Page, for example this one:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tel_Aviv (you can see the markup by clicking "edit this page"

I get this returned:

*"and given way to its reputation as a "Mediterranean metropolis that never sleeps". Haaretz Editorial It is the country's financial capital and a major performing arts and business center. Tel Aviv's urban area is the Middle East's second biggest city economy, and is ranked 42nd among global cities by Foreign Policys 2008 Global Cities Index. It is also the most expensive city in the region, and 17th most expensive city in the world. The cost of living in Israel is high, with Tel Aviv being its most expensive city to live in. According to Mercer, a human resources consulting firm based in New York, as of 2008 Tel Aviv is the most expensive city in the Middle East and the 14th most expensive in the world. It falls just behind Singapore and Paris and just ahead of Sydney and Dublin in this respect. By comparison, New York City is 22nd."*

Which isn't correct, expected result should be:

*Tel Aviv-Yafo (Hebrew: תֵּל־אָבִיב-יָפוֹ; Arabic: تل أبيب‎, Tall ʼAbīb), usually called Tel Aviv, is the second largest city in Israel, with an estimated population of 393,900. The city is situated on the Israeli Mediterranean coastline, with a land area of 51.8 square kilometres (20.0 sq mi). It is the largest and most populous city in the metropolitan area of Gush Dan, home to 3.15 million people as of 2008. The city is governed by the Tel Aviv-Yafo municipality, headed by Ron Huldai.*

For this PHP code:

```
function clean_wiki_text($text)
  {
    // first get rid of UGC HTML tags
    $text = strip_tags($text);

    // keep convert tag
    $text = preg_replace("/\{\{convert\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|[^\}]+\}\}/", "$1$2", $text);

    // remove large blocks (treat as tags)
    $text = preg_replace("/(<![^>]+>)/", '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\{\{\s?/', '<', $text);
    $text = str_replace('}}', ' />', $text);

    $text = str_replace('<! />', '', $text);

    // more wiki formatting
    $text = preg_replace("/'{2,6}/", '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[=\s]+External [lL]inks[\s=]+/", '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[=\s]+See [aA]lso[\s=]+/", '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[=\s]+References[\s=]+/", '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace("/[=\s]+Notes[\s=]+/", '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\{\{([^\}]+)\}\}/', '', $text);

    // drop page link text
    $text = preg_replace('/\[\[([^:\|\]]+)\|([^:\]]+)\]\]/', "$2", $text);
    // or keep it with preg_replace('/\[\[([^:\|\]]+)\|([^:\]]+)\]\]/', "$1 ($2)", $text);

    $text = preg_replace('/\(\[[^\]]+\]\)/', '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\[\[([^:\]]+)\]\]/', "$1", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\*?\s?\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/', '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\*\s?\[([^\s]+)\s([^\]]+)\]/', "$2", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\n(\*+\s?)/', '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\n{3,}/', "\n\n", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/<ref[^>]?>[^>]+>/', '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/<cite[^>]?>[^>]+>/', '', $text);

    $text = preg_replace('/={2,}/', '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/{?class="[^"]+"/', "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/!?\s?width="[^"]+"/', "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/!?\s?height="[^"]+"/', "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/!?\s?style="[^"]+"/', "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/!?\s?rowspan="[^"]+"/', "", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/!?\s?bgcolor="[^"]+"/', "", $text);

    $text = trim($text);

    $text = preg_replace('/\n\n/', "<br />\n<br />\n", $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\r\n\r\n/', "<br />\r\n<br />\r\n", $text);
/*
    $config = array(
      'show-body-only' => true,
      'clean'          => false, 
      'wrap'           => 0, 
      'show-warnings'  => 0,
      'show-errors'    => 0,
      'enclose-block-text'   => false,
      'vertical-space' => true,
      'output-html'    => true
    );

    // Tidy
    $tidy = new tidy;
    $tidy->parseString($text, $config, 'utf8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();

    $text = $tidy->value;
*/
    $extras = array(
  //  "/\((.*?)\)/is" => "",
      "/\[(.*?)\]/is" => ""
    );
    $text = preg_replace(array_keys($extras), array_values($extras), $text);

    $text = str_replace(" ,", ',', $text);
    $text = str_replace(", ", ',', $text);
    $text = str_replace(",", ', ', $text);
    $text = str_replace("(, ", '(', $text);
    $text = str_replace(";,", ',', $text);

    // lets keep it plain plain plain
    $text = strip_tags($text);
//    $text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text);

    $text = str_replace("|-", '', $text);
    $text = str_replace("|}", '', $text);
    $text = str_replace("|", '', $text);
    $text = str_replace('()', '', $text);
    $text = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text);

    $text = trim($text);

    $text_arr = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $result = "";
    foreach ($text_arr as $paragraph) {
      if ( mb_strlen(trim($paragraph)) > 30 ) {
      $result[] = $paragraph;
      }
    }
    return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing here, but wouldn't it be easier and safer to use Wikipedia's markup library (bundled with Mediawiki), turn that into HTML then parse it using whatever XML library you happen to be comfortable with ?

API documentation can be found at http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/ (in the `Parser` module) and it doesn't look very complicated. Basically, all you'd have to do is something like the following:

```
<?php

require_once '/path/to/mediawiki/Parser.php';
// also include whatver classes Parser depends on or use Mediawiki's autoload
// mechanism if it has any

// retrieve the content of your page in $content

$parser = new Parser();
$html   = $parser->parse($content);

$simplexml = simplexml_load_string($html);
```

Now you have a very handy SimpleXML object to play with. Of course, this only works if Mediawiki's parser produces valid XML (which I bet it does).

Also, should Mediawiki include some kind of autoload mechanism, it would be easy to find it by looking for `__autoload` or `spl_autoload_register` in Mediawiki's codebase.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to make a regex when only one example is provided - from my own experience with cleeaning wikipedia pages I know that other pages will very probably look a little different. Just to match your example is simply:

```
{{.+?}}\n
```

This only works if there is a newline after the part to be removed and if you specifiy `DOTALL` and `MULTILINE`. Match all pairs of double curly brackets and the stuff inside with:

```
{{[^}]+}}
```

You may try to do several runs, each removing another unwanted part - I doubt it's well doable to match all you need inside a single regex.

Comment: At first run this, in addition to the below code - for that page does the work, I will test a few other pages - but it looks good.

thanks